# Java RMI - Passing Objects

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi, rmi

I'm running a Java program on a `Raspberry Pi` and an `Android-App` on a smartphone. The app should be able to invoke methods running on the `Raspi`.
Since `Android` does not include the standard Java RMI package, I used `LipeRMI`: http://lipermi.sourceforge.net/

So far so good, `LipeRMI` does work well for passing primitive data types such as boolean or int.

What I want to do now is passing an `ArrayList<String>` from the Server to the app but every time I run the method, I receive following error:

```
LipeRMIException:Class java.util.ArrayList is not assignable from control.ServerInt
at lipermi.handler.CallHandler.exportObject(CallHandler.java:54)
at lipermi.handler.CallHandler.exportObject(CallHandler.java:48)
at control.RMIServer.createServer(RMIServer.java:26)
at control.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong here.

**RMIServer.java**

```
public class RMIServer implements ServerInt{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public RMIServer()  {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("50:25:5:-1");
        list.add("99:42:6:4");

        createServer();
    }

    public void createServer() {
        try {
            CallHandler callHandler = new CallHandler();
            callHandler.registerGlobal(ServerInt.class, this);
            callHandler.exportObject(ServerInt.class, list);
            Server server = new Server();
            server.bind(7777, callHandler);

            server.addServerListener(new IServerListener() {

                @Override
                public void clientDisconnected(Socket socket) {}

                @Override
                public void clientConnected(Socket socket) {}
            });

        } catch (LipeRMIException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }


    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getPWMLines() {       
        return list;
    }   
}
```

**ServerInt.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface ServerInt{          
    public ArrayList<String> getPWMLines();   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously misuse the method `CallHandler#exportObject(Class, Object)` the first parameter must be a class representing an interface and the second parameter must be an instance of a class that implements this interface. Here you provide an `ArrayList` as second parameter which is clearly not an instance of `ServerInt` that is why you get this exception.

Here is a good example of how to use this method:

```
MyRemoteListener listenerImplementation = new MyRemoteListenerImpl();
callHandler.exportObject(MyRemoteListener.class, listenerImplementation);
```

In this case the first parameter is the interface `MyRemoteListener` and the second is an instance of `MyRemoteListenerImpl` which is an implementation of the interface `MyRemoteListener`.

---

To expose your `List` you can try `callHandler.registerGlobal(List.class, list)`

Comment: Thank you for this hint :)
But how can I export the ArrayList then?

Comment: @JasOn You can't. You have to export the `RMIServer` object.

Comment: @EJP Also tried that, but everytime i try to get the ArrayList, my app crashes :/

Comment: Works fine now with your proposal, thanks for the help